# Query object within object

Tags: mongodb, passport.js

I'm using passport.js to store my users into my mongodb. A user object looks like this

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54893faf0907a100006341ee"),
    "local" : {
        "password" : [encrypted password],
        "email" : "johnsmith@domain.com"
    },
    "__v" : 0
}
```

In a mongodb shell how would I go about listing all the emails? I'm finding it difficult to do this as my data sits two level deep within the object. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`distinct`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/#db.collection.distinct) to get a list of a field's distinct values in the collection, using dot notation to reference the embedded field:

```js
db.users.distinct('local.email')
```

Comment: Cheers. Is there a way of retrieving the distinct emails and their associated password? Thanks

Comment: @sebko That would be `db.users.distinct('local')`.

Comment: Final question! I've now added a new attribute in my user model "group"

`{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54893faf0907a100006341ee"),
    "local" : {
        "password" : [encrypted password],
        "email" : "johnsmith@domain.com",
        "group" : "Super User"'
    },
    "__v" : 0
}`

Is there a way to list all users part of the "Super User" group? I've been hunting for answers but I think because I have my data two levels down it is making this complicated. Would you know any good resources to learn about this? I've got both a codeschool and treehouse subscription. Thanks Again @JohnnyHK

Comment: @sebko Probably best to post that as a new question.